# ExpressionEngine Blacklist Does Nothing

Tags: ip

I've turned on the ExpressionEngine blacklist module (V3.0.1 on EE2.8.1) and despite black listing a series of IPs (including one of my own for testing) it has made no difference. I can post to Safecracker forms from the black listed IP without any trouble.

Note I am not letting EE write to my .htaccess file as it isn't supposed to be necessary.

Comment: For the sake of testing can you set up the .htaccess part of blacklist? At least this will help us define if the issue is in the blacklist module or the channel form module. Also, (appologies for a stupid question but I'll check anyway) you are testing on a remote server correct? I mean not localhost or behind a load abalancer or cache?? It's probably easiest to echo out `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` above the form for testing.

Comment: You will need ee access to your htaccess as it will update your htaccess with ip blocking and other rules.